# How to get element values from an XML column or reaching elements within python - keep returning none

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I checked nearly everything in here about XML but nothing work about my issue. I try to parse this xml file below with my python code but it keeps returning the name, not the value within the values between columns.

XML file:

```xml
<resultsets>
<resultset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
<column name="mst1">T546FY</column>
<column name="mst2">dfghdfg</column>
<column name="mst3">2022-12-13 21:32:37.69</column>
<column name="mst4">89</column>
</row>
```

My code:

```py
for column in xroot.findall("./resultset/row/column"):
    name = column.get('name')
    rank = column.find("name='mst1'")
    print(rank,name)
```

Returns:

```
None mst1
None mst2
None mst3
None mst4
```

Comment: Have you tried `xroot.findall(".//resultset/row/column")` ?

Comment: yeah, unfortunately gave the same results, all None

Comment: Did you try using `.text()`?

Comment: putting .text() returns " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' "

Comment: How did you use it???

Comment: like this:

for column in xroot.findall("./resultset/row/column"):
    name = column.get('name')
    rank = column.find("name='mst1'").text()
    print(rank,name)

Comment: Try `column.text`.

Comment: unfortunately still keeps giving "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"  error. I tried like this: for column in xroot.findall("./resultset/row/column"): name = column.get('name') rank = column.text("name='mst1'")

Comment: Try just `rank=column.text` not `column.text("name='mst')`

Comment: works fine, thnx so much

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code like this:

```
for column in xroot.findall("./resultset/row/column"):
name = column.get('name')
rank = column.text
print(rank,name)
```

And you will get expected output

```
T546FY mst1
dfghdfg mst2
2022-12-13 21:32:37.69 mst3
89 mst4
```